# Excel misses values from numeric vector with write.table function in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, numeric

I am trying to save a data.frame from R so that it can be read from Excel. I have done this with several other data.frames that have the same structure as the one I refer to now, so far without problems. But for some reason when I try to save this data.frame and then open it with Excel, many of the numerical values in the columns FreqDev and LengthDev are not read by Excel. Instead, the rows show a string of "#" symbols.

My data.frame looks like this:

```
head(RegPartV)
     LogFreq     Word   PhonCV WordClass  FreqDev  LengthDev Irregular
1277  28.395  geweest CV-CVVCC         V 5.464336 -1.1518498     FALSE
903   25.647  gemaakt CV-CVVCC         V 4.885296 -1.1518498     FALSE
752   23.304    gehad   CV-CVC         V 4.391595 -2.1100420     FALSE
610   22.765 gebracht CV-CCVCC         V 4.278021 -0.6727537     FALSE
1312  22.041   gezegd  CV-CVCC         V 4.125465 -1.6309459     FALSE
647   21.987   gedaan  CV-CVVC         V 4.114086 -1.6309459     FALSE
```

The type of information in the data.frame is:

```
str(RegPartV)
'data.frame':   2096 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ LogFreq  : num  28.4 25.6 23.3 22.8 22 ...
 $ Word     : chr  "geweest" "gemaakt" "gehad" "gebracht" ...
 $ PhonCV   : chr  "CV-CVVCC" "CV-CVVCC" "CV-CVC" "CV-CCVCC" ...
 $ WordClass: Factor w/ 1 level "V": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ FreqDev  : num  5.46 4.89 4.39 4.28 4.13 ...
 $ LengthDev: num  -1.152 -1.152 -2.11 -0.673 -1.631 ...
 $ Irregular: logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

What is strange is that if I put my mouse over the numerical cells that now have only # symbols (in the excel file), I see a trace of the numbers that used to be there in the original R data.frame. For example, the values of these columns for the first row in the data.frame are:

```
>RegPartV[1,c(5,6)]
      FreqDev LengthDev
1277 5.464336  -1.15185
```

And if I put my mouse over the Excel cells (that contain only # symbols)  corresponding to the same values I just showed, I see:

```
54643356148468
```

and

```
-115184982188519
```

So the numbers are still there, but for some reason either R or Excel lost count of where the decimal was.

The method I am using to save the data.frame (and that I've used for structurally equivalent data.frame) is:

```
write.table(RegPartV,file="RegPartV",quote=F,sep="\t",row.names=F,col.names=T)
```

Then I open the file with Excel and I would expect to see all the info there, for some reason I'm having this numeric problem with this particular data.frame.

Any suggestions to get an Excel-readable data.frame are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the `RegPartV` with a text editor to determine whether the problem is with Excel or R. My money is on Excel.

Comment: What are the exported file contents while opened with Notepad?

Comment: @hadley The problem is indeed with Excel. If I open the file with a text editor I see all the correct information. Sadly, I need excel because I need the information to be on different cells, and opening it with a text editor just gives me the raw data. 
Jüri, I think this also answers your question. Using Notepad shows the the info correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your problem description I suspect that you have "," as the default decimal separator in Excel. Either change the default in Excel or add `dec=","` to the `write.table` command.

Comment: you were right. My default decimal separator for excel was ",", so I just added dec="," to the write.table function and now I can see the correct values in my excel file.
This is weird though, as I had used structurally equivalent files before and this is the firt time I have had this problem. In any case, things are now fixed, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That isn't actually an error: "#" means that a string/value is too long to fit into column. Widen the column and you'll see proper contents.

Comment: Thanks @Jüri but there still seems to be a problem with the numbers. The original value of the first cells of columns FreqDev and LengthDev are, respectivelly, 5.464336 and  -1.15185 but after enlarging the cells in Excel I get the values 54.643.356.148.468 and -115.184.982.188.519
So still it seems Excel is not reading the cell content well. Also, I forgot to add that there are a few values that ARE being correctly read. Namely, those that are 0.something, but those higher that 1 get messed up.